# Can anyone explain while my coin toss in blender mostly falls on its edge

Tags: physics

Totally new to blender, I made this model yesterday, and find that my coin toss experiment mostly falls on edge.

What did I misconfigure? Or is there in blender physics that prevents the model I did to properly work. I find weird when running the animation to see the coin fall, tilt to fall then raise up again.

I 'll see if I can attach the blend file here, otherwise I'll put a link.

link : [Blend file](https://filetea.me/n3wZuQSfEUQToxKUuuaVrgoRQ)

Comment: I haven’t opened you blend but from your described symptoms (fall then tilt to raise up again) most likely the objects origin isn’t at its centre of mass. To resolve this, use the ‘Set Origin’ option in the tool shelf (key ‘T’) and select ‘Origin to Centre of Mass’.

Comment: Note : when submitting questions it’s better to post images showing the problem rather than relying on people downloading your blend file. This way other people can more easily understand your problem at a glance so the solution is applicable to a wider audience.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Setting the center of mass fixed the issue (after I remove a node animation that changes the geometry).

Answer (score 2):

The Rigid Body simulation uses each objects origin as the centre of mass. If you have objects where the origin is not the centre of mass you will get unexpected behaviour such as that which you are experiencing.

For objects that are constructed of a single substance (eg, coins made of a single metal) you can use the Set Origin option in the tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>) to get Blender to automatically calculate the centre of mass from the mesh by selecting 'Origin to Centre of Mass'. This will move the origin to the centre of mass based on the mesh and the simulation should behave as would be expected.

Note that you can position the 3D cursor and use the 'Origin to 3d Cursor' option to arbitrarily position the origin (centre of mass) as desired.